# Only getting one bar in bqplot chart

Tags: python, pandas, bqplot

I have some data of the form:

Name    Score1  Score2  Score3  Score4
Bob -2  3   5   7

and im trying to use bqplot to plot a really basic bar chart

[image]

i'm trying:

```
sc_ord = OrdinalScale()
y_sc_rf = LinearScale()

bar_chart = Bars(x=data6.Name,
             y=[data6.Score1, data6.Score2, data6.Score3],
             scales={'x': sc_ord, 'y': y_sc_rf},
             labels=['Score1', 'Score2', 'Score3'],
            )

ord_ax = Axis(label='Score', scale=sc_ord, grid_lines='none')
y_ax = Axis(label='Scores', scale=y_sc_rf,  orientation='vertical', 
grid_lines='solid')

Figure(axes=[ord_ax, y_ax],  marks=[bar_chart])
```

but all im getting is one bar, i assume because Name only has one value, is there a way to set the column headers as the x data? or some other way to solve this

Comment: Happy to try another plotting package too if it makes it easier

Comment: X should be same length as y. Is the data in a pandas dataframe? Just change x to data.columns.tolist()[1:]. Or something like that.  And give the figure a title of data6.Name.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what Doug is getting at. Your length of x and y data should be the same. In this case, `x` is the column labels, and `y` is the score values. You should set the 'Name' column of your DataFrame as the index; this will prevent it from being plotted as a value.

BQPlot documentation has lots of good examples using the more complex pyplot interface which are worth reading: https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot/blob/master/examples/Marks/Object%20Model/Bars.ipynb

```
from bqplot import *
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(
    index = ['Bob'],
    columns = ['score1', 'score2', 'score3', 'score4'],
    data = [[-2, 3,5,7]]
)

sc_ord = OrdinalScale()
y_sc_rf = LinearScale()

bar_chart = Bars(x=data.columns, y = data.iloc[0],
             scales={'x': sc_ord, 'y': y_sc_rf},
             labels=data.index[1:].tolist(),
            )

ord_ax = Axis(label='Score', scale=sc_ord, grid_lines='none')
y_ax = Axis(label='Scores', scale=y_sc_rf,  orientation='vertical', 
grid_lines='solid')

Figure(axes=[ord_ax, y_ax],  marks=[bar_chart])
```

[image]